# Laravel 8 & PHP: Use Google Cloud Speech to Text API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, speech-to-text

I am currently writing an application to transcript uploaded audio files or stream urls using google cloud speech to text api.

I've created a Laravel sail project and installed the official google cloud speech php package (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-speech).

I followed the instructions and wrote this inside my AudioController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\StreamingRecognitionConfig;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AudioController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
        //$url = Storage::download('public/track.mp3');
        $url = asset('storage/test.flac');

        //$file = Storage::disk('public')->get('track.mp3');
        //$download = new Response($file, 200);


        // dd($request->all(), $url);
        return view('welcome')->with('downloadLink', $url);
    }

    public function transcribedText(Request $request)
    {
        $recognitionConfig = new RecognitionConfig();
        $recognitionConfig->setEncoding(AudioEncoding::FLAC);
        $recognitionConfig->setSampleRateHertz(44100);
        $recognitionConfig->setLanguageCode('en-US');
        $config = new StreamingRecognitionConfig();
        $config->setConfig($recognitionConfig);
        $file = Storage::disk('public')->get('test.flac');
        // dd($file);
        // $audioResource = fopen($file, 'r');

        $responses = $speechClient->recognizeAudioStream($config, $file);

        foreach ($responses as $element) {
            dd($element);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but I get following error, although I've followed the offical documentation and installed everything properly:
**"Undefined variable $speechClient"**

My IDE Plugin Inteliphase marks the imported packages red and states:
**"Undefined type 'Google\Cloud\Speech\V1...'.intelephense(1009)"**

Did I miss something ?

[image: error]
[image: code]
[image: controller]

Comment: You didn't define `$speechClient`, so there's nothing to use.

Comment: Where I have to define this? Offical documentation is not mentioning something regarding creating a $speechClient var

Comment: Yes, the official documentation kinda sucks. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-speech/search?q=speechclient shows a few options on how to define it. `$speechClient = new SpeechClient();` should work, I think